# Socket failed to connect before handshake nodeJS

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, socket.io, digital-ocean, mean.io

I am using [socket.io](https://github.com/Automattic/socket.io) in project build on top of [MEAN.IO](https://github.com/linnovate/mean).
I integrated the library successfully , on my local everything is working fine with no errors in console, but on deploying the same code on server it shows me an error as

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://ip.ip.ip.ip:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=OpeM3YIJqVuTnt-dAAAY' failed: Connection closed before receiving a handshake response .
```

After searching a bit I figure out that this is happening because of fact that I am using cluster with nodejs , so to avoid this I need to have a [sticky section](http://socket.io/docs/using-multiple-nodes/) , I found a module for it as well , [sticky-session](https://github.com/indutny/sticky-session) , just need help in configuring this module .

P.S :- I am using latest version of socket.io

Answer (score 0):

This was the problem with [sticky-session](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sticky-session), I was using socket with cluster (supported by mean.io in production mode) and hence the inter core communication was not working properly .